# Authentication with Flutter Bloc/Cubit

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-development, flutter-bloc, cubit

How do I set current user using hydrated storage instead of cachedClient
Like its done in bloc docs for firebase login?

*They wrote in user repository:*

```
     Stream<User> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((firebaseUser) {
      final user = firebaseUser == null ? User.empty : firebaseUser.toUser;
      _cache.write(key: userCacheKey, value: user);
      return user;
    });
   }

    User get currentUser {
        return _cache.read<User>(key: userCacheKey) ?? User.empty;
      }
```

I have ***isEmpty/isNotEmpty*** in my User model but in firebase there is a getter current user where cachedClient used

In my user repository i only have

```
Future<User> getUser({required String username, required String password}) async
```

and thats it

But for changing status they added new bloc where they read this current user to set authenticated/unauthenticated

This is how its done for firebase login: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial?id=authentication-repository